# Как добавить папки с файлами в дочернюю тему?

Tags: wordpress

Создала дочернюю тему, файл стилей `style.css` и внесла в него свои изменения. Работает.
Но в главной теме есть папка с файлом `/inc/template-tags.php` которую по аналогии так же копирую и изменяю файл. Но изменения не вступают в силу.
Почему?
В начале файла я попыталась изменить название темы, не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Почему?

Возможно потому, что некоторые функции родительской тем сделаны без учёта дочки.

Если в `/inc/template-tags.php` нужная функция проверяется на существование (`if ( !function_exists()`), то проще (да и правильнее) скопировать её в файл функций дочерней темы  и изменить как хочется.

Comment: да есть такие строчки там, то есть надо скопировать из этого файл в файл functions.php дочерней темы, правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Vick? да полностью скопировать функцию и потом менять её как хочется.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны скопировать файл, сохраняя путь. Тоесть, в папке с дочерной темой создать папку inc, и уже в нее скопировать файл.

Comment: это итак ясно. делала. но эти файлы не работают в теме. сохраняется приоритет за оригинальной темой а не файлом который расположен в дочерней теме по такому же адресу и папке